# Asynchronus functions

Tags: javascript

When a window.alert() is called, the script shouldnt wait for the user input(clicking ok for example), it should continue.

How could I achieve that **without** using the setTimeout() function?

```
this.alert('Window')
console.log('Continue here, dont wait for user input on the "Window"')
```

Comment: `alert` is blocking.. Use some custom UI to display alert instead of `window.alert`

Comment: you can't block in javascript.

Comment: @Faizy the keyword is `modal box` take a look at that topic.

Comment: @DanielA.White, try this `console.time("alert");
alert("...waiting");
console.timeEnd("alert");` If you cannot block, the measured duration should be like < 1ms

Comment: @Thomas you can't block other than those functions....

Comment: Without using `setTimeout`? I am afraid it won't help either.

Answer (score 2):

No. JavaScript is single threaded. You simply can't. Unless the user input hook is completed, thread pauses there.

You can just tweak/have the DOM look like an alert with styling (weird but *ok*).

Answer (score 1):

The alert function will pause any further execution of javascript until the user clicks the OK button because the code all runs in a single thread.

You may find this question useful as it addresses the precise problem you are trying to overcome.

[Prevent alert() from halting the execution of JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203157/prevent-alert-from-halting-the-execution-of-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Since JavaScript runs on single thread, alert/prompt/confirm will pause the execution until response is received from user.

But there are ways you can prevent this:-
1. Use custom UI instead of browser's.
2. By using WebWorkers API
3. By using setTimeout/setInterval
4. By using requestNextFrame function