# How to get alert Box with sound?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, audio, alert

I am trying to get alert like pop-up with sound when the balls collide. When I use alert function it gets freeze and it will keep on showing alert. As far as now i tried to get alert like in text. But how to get alert with sound(eg.beep) ? 
I have attached the code snippet. Can anyone help to get this.
Thanks in advance

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById("Canvas").getContext("2d");
const containerR = 150;
const size = containerR * 2
ctx.canvas.width = ctx.canvas.height = size;
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.8

const getBall = (x, y, dx, dy, r, color) => ({x, y, dx, dy, r, color});

const balls = [
  getBall(size / 2, size - 30, 1, 1, 8, "Green"),
  getBall(size / 3, size - 50, 1, 1, 8, "Green"),
  getBall(size / 4, size - 60, 1, 1, 8, "Green"),
  getBall(size / 2, size / 5,  1, 1, 8,  "Green"),
];

const drawBall = (ball) => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = ball.collider ? "red" : ball.color;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

const updatePos = (ball) => {

  ball.x += ball.dx;
  ball.y += ball.dy;
  const dx = ball.x - containerR;
  const dy = ball.y - containerR;

  if (Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) >= containerR - ball.r) {
    const v = Math.sqrt(ball.dx * ball.dx + ball.dy * ball.dy);
    const angleToCollisionPoint = Math.atan2(-dy, dx);
    const oldAngle = Math.atan2(-ball.dy, ball.dx);
    const newAngle = 2 * angleToCollisionPoint - oldAngle;
    ball.dx = -v * Math.cos(newAngle);
    ball.dy = v * Math.sin(newAngle);
  }
}


const collides = (a, b) => (Math.hypot(Math.abs(a.x - b.x), Math.abs(a.y - b.y)) < (a.r + b.r));

function engine() {
  //console.clear(); // Clear console test messages
  mydiv.textContent =" ";
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

  balls.forEach((a, ai) => {
    a.collider = undefined;
    
    balls.forEach((b, bi) => {
      if (bi === ai) return; // Don't look at self
      if (collides(a, b)) a.collider = b; // Store the colliding B ball
    });
    
    if (a.collider) { // If ball has a collider:
     mydiv.textContent = ("Alert");
      //console.log(`${a.color[0]} → ← ${a.collider.color[0]}`);
    }
    
    updatePos(a);
    drawBall(a);
  });

  requestAnimationFrame(engine);
}

engine();
```

```css
<style>
canvas {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #000;
}
</style>
```

```html
<html>
<canvas id="Canvas"></canvas>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<div id="y"></div>
<div id="dx"></div>
<div id="dy"></div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use normal `.alert()` [without halting the javascript execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203157/prevent-alert-from-halting-the-execution-of-javascript) so you have to stick with HTML alert/prompt (there is many libraries out there provide neat and customizable UI),  for the beep sound, you can just use [based64](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) data with [data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), this snippet here wont work because the SO snippets are sandbox, here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mamounothman/vey0Lx9d/6/) you can improve.

the beep sound example based on this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879152/how-do-i-make-javascript-beep#answer-23395136)

**Update**: I added the custom alert and its based on this example from [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/async-dialogs.html) implementation, there is custom HTML and CSS, and Javascript `PromptDialog()`, basically this Javascript object implementation is asynchronous ans doesn't block the execution, please refer to the linked bluebird article for more information since its a guide on how to build it and it explains everything better than me.

```js
function beep() {
    var snd = new Audio("data:audio/wav;base64,//uQRAAAAWMSLwUIYAAsYkXgoQwAEaYLWfkWgAI0wWs/ItAAAGDgYtAgAyN+QWaAAihwMWm4G8QQRDiMcCBcH3Cc+CDv/7xA4Tvh9Rz/y8QADBwMWgQAZG/ILNAARQ4GLTcDeIIIhxGOBAuD7hOfBB3/94gcJ3w+o5/5eIAIAAAVwWgQAVQ2ORaIQwEMAJiDg95G4nQL7mQVWI6GwRcfsZAcsKkJvxgxEjzFUgfHoSQ9Qq7KNwqHwuB13MA4a1q/DmBrHgPcmjiGoh//EwC5nGPEmS4RcfkVKOhJf+WOgoxJclFz3kgn//dBA+ya1GhurNn8zb//9NNutNuhz31f////9vt///z+IdAEAAAK4LQIAKobHItEIYCGAExBwe8jcToF9zIKrEdDYIuP2MgOWFSE34wYiR5iqQPj0JIeoVdlG4VD4XA67mAcNa1fhzA1jwHuTRxDUQ//iYBczjHiTJcIuPyKlHQkv/LHQUYkuSi57yQT//uggfZNajQ3Vmz+Zt//+mm3Wm3Q576v////+32///5/EOgAAADVghQAAAAA//uQZAUAB1WI0PZugAAAAAoQwAAAEk3nRd2qAAAAACiDgAAAAAAABCqEEQRLCgwpBGMlJkIz8jKhGvj4k6jzRnqasNKIeoh5gI7BJaC1A1AoNBjJgbyApVS4IDlZgDU5WUAxEKDNmmALHzZp0Fkz1FMTmGFl1FMEyodIavcCAUHDWrKAIA4aa2oCgILEBupZgHvAhEBcZ6joQBxS76AgccrFlczBvKLC0QI2cBoCFvfTDAo7eoOQInqDPBtvrDEZBNYN5xwNwxQRfw8ZQ5wQVLvO8OYU+mHvFLlDh05Mdg7BT6YrRPpCBznMB2r//xKJjyyOh+cImr2/4doscwD6neZjuZR4AgAABYAAAABy1xcdQtxYBYYZdifkUDgzzXaXn98Z0oi9ILU5mBjFANmRwlVJ3/6jYDAmxaiDG3/6xjQQCCKkRb/6kg/wW+kSJ5//rLobkLSiKmqP/0ikJuDaSaSf/6JiLYLEYnW/+kXg1WRVJL/9EmQ1YZIsv/6Qzwy5qk7/+tEU0nkls3/zIUMPKNX/6yZLf+kFgAfgGyLFAUwY//uQZAUABcd5UiNPVXAAAApAAAAAE0VZQKw9ISAAACgAAAAAVQIygIElVrFkBS+Jhi+EAuu+lKAkYUEIsmEAEoMeDmCETMvfSHTGkF5RWH7kz/ESHWPAq/kcCRhqBtMdokPdM7vil7RG98A2sc7zO6ZvTdM7pmOUAZTnJW+NXxqmd41dqJ6mLTXxrPpnV8avaIf5SvL7pndPvPpndJR9Kuu8fePvuiuhorgWjp7Mf/PRjxcFCPDkW31srioCExivv9lcwKEaHsf/7ow2Fl1T/9RkXgEhYElAoCLFtMArxwivDJJ+bR1HTKJdlEoTELCIqgEwVGSQ+hIm0NbK8WXcTEI0UPoa2NbG4y2K00JEWbZavJXkYaqo9CRHS55FcZTjKEk3NKoCYUnSQ0rWxrZbFKbKIhOKPZe1cJKzZSaQrIyULHDZmV5K4xySsDRKWOruanGtjLJXFEmwaIbDLX0hIPBUQPVFVkQkDoUNfSoDgQGKPekoxeGzA4DUvnn4bxzcZrtJyipKfPNy5w+9lnXwgqsiyHNeSVpemw4bWb9psYeq//uQZBoABQt4yMVxYAIAAAkQoAAAHvYpL5m6AAgAACXDAAAAD59jblTirQe9upFsmZbpMudy7Lz1X1DYsxOOSWpfPqNX2WqktK0DMvuGwlbNj44TleLPQ+Gsfb+GOWOKJoIrWb3cIMeeON6lz2umTqMXV8Mj30yWPpjoSa9ujK8SyeJP5y5mOW1D6hvLepeveEAEDo0mgCRClOEgANv3B9a6fikgUSu/DmAMATrGx7nng5p5iimPNZsfQLYB2sDLIkzRKZOHGAaUyDcpFBSLG9MCQALgAIgQs2YunOszLSAyQYPVC2YdGGeHD2dTdJk1pAHGAWDjnkcLKFymS3RQZTInzySoBwMG0QueC3gMsCEYxUqlrcxK6k1LQQcsmyYeQPdC2YfuGPASCBkcVMQQqpVJshui1tkXQJQV0OXGAZMXSOEEBRirXbVRQW7ugq7IM7rPWSZyDlM3IuNEkxzCOJ0ny2ThNkyRai1b6ev//3dzNGzNb//4uAvHT5sURcZCFcuKLhOFs8mLAAEAt4UWAAIABAAAAAB4qbHo0tIjVkUU//uQZAwABfSFz3ZqQAAAAAngwAAAE1HjMp2qAAAAACZDgAAAD5UkTE1UgZEUExqYynN1qZvqIOREEFmBcJQkwdxiFtw0qEOkGYfRDifBui9MQg4QAHAqWtAWHoCxu1Yf4VfWLPIM2mHDFsbQEVGwyqQoQcwnfHeIkNt9YnkiaS1oizycqJrx4KOQjahZxWbcZgztj2c49nKmkId44S71j0c8eV9yDK6uPRzx5X18eDvjvQ6yKo9ZSS6l//8elePK/Lf//IInrOF/FvDoADYAGBMGb7FtErm5MXMlmPAJQVgWta7Zx2go+8xJ0UiCb8LHHdftWyLJE0QIAIsI+UbXu67dZMjmgDGCGl1H+vpF4NSDckSIkk7Vd+sxEhBQMRU8j/12UIRhzSaUdQ+rQU5kGeFxm+hb1oh6pWWmv3uvmReDl0UnvtapVaIzo1jZbf/pD6ElLqSX+rUmOQNpJFa/r+sa4e/pBlAABoAAAAA3CUgShLdGIxsY7AUABPRrgCABdDuQ5GC7DqPQCgbbJUAoRSUj+NIEig0YfyWUho1VBBBA//uQZB4ABZx5zfMakeAAAAmwAAAAF5F3P0w9GtAAACfAAAAAwLhMDmAYWMgVEG1U0FIGCBgXBXAtfMH10000EEEEEECUBYln03TTTdNBDZopopYvrTTdNa325mImNg3TTPV9q3pmY0xoO6bv3r00y+IDGid/9aaaZTGMuj9mpu9Mpio1dXrr5HERTZSmqU36A3CumzN/9Robv/Xx4v9ijkSRSNLQhAWumap82WRSBUqXStV/YcS+XVLnSS+WLDroqArFkMEsAS+eWmrUzrO0oEmE40RlMZ5+ODIkAyKAGUwZ3mVKmcamcJnMW26MRPgUw6j+LkhyHGVGYjSUUKNpuJUQoOIAyDvEyG8S5yfK6dhZc0Tx1KI/gviKL6qvvFs1+bWtaz58uUNnryq6kt5RzOCkPWlVqVX2a/EEBUdU1KrXLf40GoiiFXK///qpoiDXrOgqDR38JB0bw7SoL+ZB9o1RCkQjQ2CBYZKd/+VJxZRRZlqSkKiws0WFxUyCwsKiMy7hUVFhIaCrNQsKkTIsLivwKKigsj8XYlwt/WKi2N4d//uQRCSAAjURNIHpMZBGYiaQPSYyAAABLAAAAAAAACWAAAAApUF/Mg+0aohSIRobBAsMlO//Kk4soosy1JSFRYWaLC4qZBYWFRGZdwqKiwkNBVmoWFSJkWFxX4FFRQWR+LsS4W/rFRb/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////VEFHAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAU291bmRib3kuZGUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMjAwNGh0dHA6Ly93d3cuc291bmRib3kuZGUAAAAAAAAAACU=");  
    snd.play();
}


var noop = function() {
  return this;
};

function UserCanceledError() {
  this.name = 'UserCanceledError';
  this.message = 'User canceled dialog';
}
UserCanceledError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);

function Dialog() {
  this.setCallbacks(noop, noop);
}
Dialog.prototype.setCallbacks = function(okCallback, cancelCallback) {
  this._okCallback     = okCallback;
  return this;
};
Dialog.prototype.waitForUser = function() {
  var _this = this;
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    _this.setCallbacks(resolve, reject);
  });
};

Dialog.prototype.show = noop;
Dialog.prototype.hide = noop;

function PromptDialog() {
  Dialog.call(this);
  this.el           = document.getElementById('dialog');
  this.messageEl    = this.el.querySelector('.message');
  this.okButton     = this.el.querySelector('button.ok');
  this.attachDomEvents();
}
PromptDialog.prototype = Object.create(Dialog.prototype);
PromptDialog.prototype.attachDomEvents = function() {
  var _this = this;
  this.okButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    _this.hide();
    console.log('Ok clicked!!');
  });
  
};
PromptDialog.prototype.show = function(message) {
  this.messageEl.innerHTML = '' + message;
  this.el.className = '';
  return this;
};
PromptDialog.prototype.hide = function() {
  this.el.className = 'hidden';
  return this;
};



const ctx = document.getElementById("Canvas").getContext("2d");
const containerR = 150;
const size = containerR * 2
ctx.canvas.width = ctx.canvas.height = size;
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.8


var prompt = new PromptDialog();

const getBall = (x, y, dx, dy, r, color) => ({x, y, dx, dy, r, color});

const balls = [
  getBall(size / 2, size - 30, 1, 1, 8, "Green"),
  getBall(size / 3, size - 50, 1, 1, 8, "Green"),
  getBall(size / 4, size - 60, 1, 1, 8, "Green"),
  getBall(size / 2, size / 5,  1, 1, 8,  "Green"),
];

const drawBall = (ball) => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = ball.collider ? "red" : ball.color;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

const updatePos = (ball) => {

  ball.x += ball.dx;
  ball.y += ball.dy;
  const dx = ball.x - containerR;
  const dy = ball.y - containerR;

  if (Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) >= containerR - ball.r) {
    const v = Math.sqrt(ball.dx * ball.dx + ball.dy * ball.dy);
    const angleToCollisionPoint = Math.atan2(-dy, dx);
    const oldAngle = Math.atan2(-ball.dy, ball.dx);
    const newAngle = 2 * angleToCollisionPoint - oldAngle;
    ball.dx = -v * Math.cos(newAngle);
    ball.dy = v * Math.sin(newAngle);
  }
}


const collides = (a, b) => (Math.hypot(Math.abs(a.x - b.x), Math.abs(a.y - b.y)) < (a.r + b.r));

function engine() {
  //console.clear(); // Clear console test messages
  mydiv.textContent =" ";
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

  balls.forEach((a, ai) => {
    a.collider = undefined;
    
    balls.forEach((b, bi) => {
      if (bi === ai) return; // Don't look at self
      if (collides(a, b)) a.collider = b; // Store the colliding B ball
    });
    
    if (a.collider) { // If ball has a collider:
     mydiv.textContent = ("Alert");
     beep();
     
     
     prompt.show('collision detected')
      .waitForUser()
      .then(function(name) {
        output.innerHTML = '' + name;
      })
      .catch(function(e) {
        console.log('Unknown error', e);
      })
      .finally(function() {
        prompt.hide();
      });
      
      //console.log(`${a.color[0]} → ← ${a.collider.color[0]}`);
    }
    
    updatePos(a);
    drawBall(a);
  });

  requestAnimationFrame(engine);
}

engine();
```

```css
canvas {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #000;
}

#dialog {
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  border: thin solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="Canvas"></canvas>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<div id="y"></div>
<div id="dx"></div>
<div id="dy"></div>

<div id="dialog" class="hidden">
  <div class="message"></div>
  <div>
    <button class="ok">Ok</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your vision..that sound part it really works...i have to get the alert text to be in pop-up box something like that..can you give me a suggestions?

Comment: @Anonymous, glad to help,  the only way to have a pop-up alert without halting the execution of javascript, is to implement your own alert using HTML/CSS/JS if you want I can suggest a solution.

Comment: sorry for the late reply...implementing own alert ? Please suggest a solution

Comment: @Anonymous, I updated my answer, sorry for late response here too, but really was busy today! I updated the snippet and the fiddle, the fiddle not sure why the js view take the dialog to far to the right. but it will work locally and here, please accept it as answer if you find it useful to you.

Comment: @Anonymous Thanks for your help. This is what I am looking for a past couple of days.

Comment: @Anonymous, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: User interaction**

you can add an audio tag and play it for sound

note: in newer browser chrome ^50, you need user interaction to audio tag work fine

```js
const startBtn = document.getElementById("start-btn")
const sound = document.getElementById("beeb-player")
const ctx = document.getElementById("Canvas").getContext("2d");
const containerR = 150;
const size = containerR * 2
ctx.canvas.width = ctx.canvas.height = size;
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.8

const getBall = (x, y, dx, dy, r, color) => ({x, y, dx, dy, r, color});

const balls = [
  getBall(size / 2, size - 30, 1, 1, 8, "Green"),
  getBall(size / 3, size - 50, 1, 1, 8, "Green"),
  getBall(size / 4, size - 60, 1, 1, 8, "Green"),
  getBall(size / 2, size / 5,  1, 1, 8,  "Green"),
];

const drawBall = (ball) => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = ball.collider ? "red" : ball.color;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

const updatePos = (ball) => {

  ball.x += ball.dx;
  ball.y += ball.dy;
  const dx = ball.x - containerR;
  const dy = ball.y - containerR;

  if (Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) >= containerR - ball.r) {
    const v = Math.sqrt(ball.dx * ball.dx + ball.dy * ball.dy);
    const angleToCollisionPoint = Math.atan2(-dy, dx);
    const oldAngle = Math.atan2(-ball.dy, ball.dx);
    const newAngle = 2 * angleToCollisionPoint - oldAngle;
    ball.dx = -v * Math.cos(newAngle);
    ball.dy = v * Math.sin(newAngle);
  }
}


const collides = (a, b) => (Math.hypot(Math.abs(a.x - b.x), Math.abs(a.y - b.y)) < (a.r + b.r));

function engine() {
  //console.clear(); // Clear console test messages
  mydiv.textContent =" ";
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

  balls.forEach((a, ai) => {
    a.collider = undefined;
    
    balls.forEach((b, bi) => {
      if (bi === ai) return; // Don't look at self
      if (collides(a, b)) a.collider = b; // Store the colliding B ball
    });
    
    if (a.collider) { // If ball has a collider:
     mydiv.textContent = ("Alert");
     sound.play()
//console.log(`${a.color[0]} → ← ${a.collider.color[0]}`);
    }
    
    updatePos(a);
    drawBall(a);
  });

  requestAnimationFrame(engine);
}

startBtn.addEventListener('click', engine, {once:true})
```

```css
<style>
canvas {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #000;
}
</style>
```

```html
<html>
<button id="start-btn">start</button>
<canvas id="Canvas"></canvas>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<div id="y"></div>
<div id="dx"></div>
<div id="dy"></div>
<audio src="http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=1815&type=mp3" id="beeb-player"></audio>
</html>
```

you can add an audio tag and play it when the balls collide

```js
function alertWithSound() {
const el = document.getElementById("beeb-player")
el.play()
}
```

```html
<audio src="http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=1815&type=mp3" id="beeb-player"></audio>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help..i tried this as well but its not working

Comment: you are right
I forget about user interaction (you need user interaction for play a sound in new browsers https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/play-request-was-interrupted) 
I update my answer